# My VS 2022 doesn't handle over than 32 bit bitset

Tags: c++, bitset

I am trying to convert 45 bit binary number into a hex number but when compiling, I get overflow error, but when applying the code on online C++ compiler, it works. My platform is X64. Any help please.

```
int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    string binary_str("111000000100010010100000110101001000100011000");
    bitset<45> n(binary_str);

    string f;
    ss << hex << n.to_ulong() << endl;  // error happens here 
    f = ss.str();
    cout << f;
    return 0;
}
```

When compile this code above on online C++ compiler I get a correct result which is OX1c08941a9118.

Comment: Do you really have set your compiler to x64? Maybe you are compiling for 32bit?

Comment: @Klaus My VS-2022 gives the error when using a string longer than 32 chars, and it is set for 64-bit build.

Comment: Windows uses the [LLP64 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), so ulong has 32-bits.  You must use [to_ullong()] (https://cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_ullong) instead.

Comment: I was confused by the sentence, that a online compiler delivers a different result/behavior. I thought it was also msvs compiler... if it is a different compiler... ok :-)

Comment: @Klaus I used https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler to run the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsigned long` is 32bit with MSVC. Also when compiling for x64. You need `unsigned long long` to get a 64bit integer, so in this case you can use [`to_ullong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong):

```
ss << hex << n.to_ullong() << endl;
```

Comment: Nailed it! Answers are so obvious when someone else tells you them. :)

Comment: Thats exactly why it is a good idea to use uint64_t instead :-) ... which not helps in that case as there is no n.to(uint64_t&) version... bitset should improve the interface :-)

Comment: @harold   thank you so much! It works now with to_ullong()

Comment: @Klaus when I go to Configuration Manager on MSVS the Active solution platform is x64. Is that where to make sure I am compiling on 64-bit or not? Thanks

Comment: @Code_Student usually yes, but you can also configure individual projects to compile for a different platform than the active solution platform